# What is the meaning of the word "cop-flat"?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

From the novel *Obsession in Death* by J.D. Robb (Nora Roberts), 2015:

> To discourage any more questions, Eve turned away. She and Peabody had sealed up on entering the apartment. She’d turned on her recorder before stepping into the bedroom. Now she stood a moment, a tall, slim woman with short, tousled brown hair, with long-lidded eyes of gilded brown **cop-flat** in her angular face.

I don't know the meaning of the word *cop-flat*. I have searched all the relevant materials on the internet, but I still couldn't find what this word means. Please advise.

Comment: Without more information, I don't think this question can be answered. Was the woman a police officer? That's the only way I can see this making any sense at all.

Comment: That's because the writer must have just coined it but for the life of me I can't figure out what it means.

Comment: @Lambie So you don't think my answer is correct? Why not?

Comment: @linguisticturn No, I am saying given the lack of context, I could not figure it out. Is that allowed? And even if some cops have a flat look in their eyes to mean unexpressive, many cops have mean eyes, too. So....If it had been: cop-flat eyes, I might have gotten it sooner.

Comment: @Lambie Oh, sure, sorry. I was just making sure I wasn't missing something in my answer.

Comment: @BennyChan What would really help in clarifying your question is to emphasize that Eve is a police officer, indeed a homicide detective, and that in this particular passage she's investigating a murder scene. Also you can include a link to the relevant page on google books, namely [this one](https://books.google.com/books?id=0lsCDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA5&dq=%22Now%20she%20stood%20a%20moment%2C%20a%20tall%2C%20slim%20woman%20with%20short%2C%20tousled%20brown%20hair%2C%20with%20long-lidded%20eyes%20of%20gilded%20brown%20cop-flat%20in%20her%20angular%20face.%22&pg=PA5#v=onepage&q=%22cop-flat%22&f=false).

Comment: I certainly will do so next time and it is good to know so much about this word. I have to know what it means before I do the translation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a non-standard usage (0/50 relevant hits in the first 50 Google hits for "cop-flat"); perhaps LiteratureSE is the correct site.

Comment: She’s a cop, and her eyes have a flat (expressionless) gaze. VTC

Answer (score 25):

As Robusto suspected (see the comments), the protagonist, [Lieutenant Eve Dallas](https://books.google.com/books?id=G8TURPL1YLMC&lpg=PA13&dq=%22cop-flat%22&pg=PA9#v=onepage&q=%22Lieutenant%20Eve%20Dallas%22&f=false), is indeed a police officer. She is the heroine in the [*…in Death*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_Death)  series of novels by the author J. D. Robb (real name [Nora Roberts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nora_Roberts)). In the series, Lieutenant Dallas's eyes are several times described as *cop-flat,* meaning, unexpressive and unreadable eyes of a police officer.

## The meaning of *cop-flat*

That *cop-flat* means, roughly, 'unexpressive and unreadable eyes of a police officer' is especially clear here, in a passage from another novel in the series:

> Her narrow, angular face was set, the long golden brown eyes **cop flat**. Unreadable even to him.

(from [*Divided in Death*](https://books.google.com/books?id=_EuAtTlR8mIC&lpg=PT17&dq=%22cop-flat%22&pg=PT22#v=onepage&q=cop-flat&f=false))

So to say that Eve's eyes are *cop-flat* is to say that eyes of cops are often characteristically ***flat,*** and that Eve's eyes were just like that. Here the relevant dictionary meaning of *flat* is 'lacking in animation, zest, or vigor : dull' [(*Merriam-Webster*)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flat); 'lacking interest or emotion; dull and lifeless' [(*Oxford Dictionaries*)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/flat#flat); 'Wanting in points of attraction and interest; prosaic, dull, uninteresting, lifeless, monotonous, insipid.' (Sometimes with allusion to *flat drink*, i.e. one that has lost its flavour or sharpness; dead, insipid, stale.) 'Said of composition, discourse, a joke, etc. Also of a person with reference to his composition, conversation, etc.' (*OED*).

## Parsing the sentence quoted by the OP

The passage quoted by the OP is from [*Obsession in Death*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0lsCDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA5&ots=1bqqLV1vu3&dq=%22Now%20she%20stood%20a%20moment%2C%20a%20tall%2C%20slim%20woman%20with%20short%2C%20tousled%20brown%20hair%2C%20with%20long-lidded%20eyes%20of%20gilded%20brown%20cop-flat%20in%20her%20angular%20face.%22&pg=PA5#v=onepage&q=%22Now%20she%20stood%20a%20moment,%20a%20tall,%20slim%20woman%20with%20short,%20tousled%20brown%20hair,%20with%20long-lidded%20eyes%20of%20gilded%20brown%20cop-flat%20in%20her%20angular%20face.%22&f=false). The sentence

> Now she stood a moment, a tall, slim woman with short, tousled brown hair, with long-lidded eyes of gilded brown **cop-flat** in her angular face.

is relatively difficult to parse and it may even seem at first glance that *cop-flat* is used as a noun—indeed, it might seem that *gilded brown cop-flat* is a nominal (a noun phrase without a determiner), where the adjective phrase *gilded brown* modifies the noun *cop-flat*. But that is not so. Here is the same sentence, where I've restored some words that were ellipted in the original:

> …a tall, slim woman… with long-lidded eyes of gilded brown ***color that were*** cop-flat in her angular face.

Here is an analogous construction, where *wet from the rain* plays the role of *cop-flat in her angular face*:

> *This is a woman with shoes of beautiful purple [color that were] wet from the rain.*

Here *color that were* can be ellipted without changing the meaning of the sentence, though it will be harder to parse.

## Other examples of usage of *cop-flat*

Here are some other instances from the series where Eve's eyes are described as *cop-flat*:

> Bystanders gathered just outside the sidewalk barricades. She scanned them with eyes the color of good Irish whiskey, and **cop flat**. And spotted the witness in the back of a blackand-white.

(from [*Mirror, Mirror*](https://books.google.com/books?id=G8TURPL1YLMC&lpg=PA13&dq=%22She%20scanned%20them%20with%20eyes%20the%20color%20of%20good%20Irish%20whiskey%2C%20and%20cop%20flat.%22&pg=PA14#v=onepage&q=%22She%20scanned%20them%20with%20eyes%20the%20color%20of%20good%20Irish%20whiskey,%20and%20cop%20flat.%22&f=false))

> She paused, her eyes going **cop flat.**

(from [*Loyalty in Death*](https://books.google.com/books?id=2WF5kJax0P4C&lpg=PT117&dq=%22cop-flat%22&pg=PT117#v=onepage&q=%22cop-flat%22&f=false))

In addition, at least one other author has used *cop-flat,* too:

> Those eyes would be her best feature, except they were **cop flat.**

(from [*Reluctant Burglar*](https://books.google.com/books?id=3kt69SnRSQgC&lpg=PA245&dq=%22cop-flat%22&pg=PA245#v=onepage&q=%22cop-flat%22&f=false) by Jill Elizabeth Nelson)

Finally, a related construction appears in yet another book:

> Billard tilted his head to the side and regarded Coop with his **cop's flat eyes.**

(from [*The Night Caller*](https://books.google.com/books?id=gXWnJZ-h7j4C&lpg=PA32&ots=VLAgBV-3xc&dq=%22cop-flat%20eyes%22&pg=PA31#v=onepage&q=%22cop-flat%22&f=false) by John Lutz)

## The grammar of *cop-flat*

Based on various parts of [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468), it seems that *cop-flat* is best considered an **adjective-centred compound adjective.** If that is right, then it should always be hyphenated (contrary to how it appears in many of the books mentioned above). In particular, *cop-flat* should not be considered a syntactic construction, i.e. it shouldn't be considered an adjective phrase (AdjP) in which a noun modifes an adjective. According to CGEL, 'adjectives take only a highly restricted type of NP [noun phrase] as pre-head dependent' (p. 1656). On pp. 549–550, CGEL lists the allowable types of NP pre-head dependents: they are either measure phrases (as in ***three years*** old, **five centimetres** thick, **a foot** wide, **two hours** long, …), or else quantificational NPs (as in ***a bit*** lax, **a smidgin** overripe, **a tad** greasy, **a trifle** shy, **plenty** big enough, …). Some quantificational ones occur only with comparatives (***a great deal*** smaller, **a (whole) lot** different, **lots** better, **heaps** worse, …). But in all cases, notice they are truly complete noun phrases (NPs), meaning that they include a determiner when one is necessary. In contrast, we have ***cop***-flat, not ****a cop*** flat. This is an indication that we are not dealing with a syntactic construction (an adjective phrase), but rather with a compound one.

Here is the relevant discussion from CGEL (p. 1656).

> ### 4.3.1 Adjective-centred compound adjectives
>
> ■ Noun + adjective compounds
>
> The majority of compounds with an adjective as second component have a noun as the first. In general, there is no contrast here between a compound and a syntactic construction since adjectives take only a highly restricted type of NP as pre-head dependent (cf. Ch. 6, §3.2): the syntactic dependents of adjectives are generally pre-head adverbs or post-head PPs and clauses. Many noun + adjective compounds involve a high degree of lexicalisation, as in:
>
> [25]  *colour-fast    foot-loose    headstrong    threadbare    top-heavy*
>
> Although there is a more or less obvious connection between the meaning of the whole and that of the adjective head, none of these satisfy the test for [hyponymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy_and_hypernymy). *He is headstrong,* for example, does not entail *He is strong,* and something can be top heavy even though it is as a whole relatively light. We will not attempt a comprehensive review of the patterns to be found, but will illustrate a selection of the more productive ones.
>
> ### Comparative/intensifying
>
> [26]  i  *bone-dry          crystal-clear    dirt-cheap      dog-tired         feather-light*
>                *ice-cold             paper-thin       razor-sharp    rock-hard       stone-deaf*
>            ii  *bottle-green    brick-red          jet-black          snow-white    steel-blue*
>
> Here the noun indicates a standard of comparison: "dry as a bone", "clear as crystal", etc. Very often, as in [i], the effect is to intensify: *bone-dry* means "extremely/completely dry", and so on. A special case of the comparative type is that of colour adjectives, as in [ii]; *jet-black* and *snow-white* are intensifying, but the others simply specify a particular shade of the colour. Compounds of this type are clearly hyponymic: if you are dog-tired, then necessarily you are tired, and so on.
>
> ### Measure terms
>
> [27]  *ankle-deep    shoulder-high    skin-deep    state-wide    week-long*
>
> This is a productive pattern, with the noun indicating extent. *Wide* here has to do with area rather than the one-dimensional measure denoted by *wide* on its own, and *skin-deep* "superficial" is a further example of lexicalisation. Compounds formed on this pattern are non-hyponymic: *The water was ankle-deep,* for example, does not entail *The water was deep.* We noted earlier that there may be a variety of reasons why a compound might fail the hyponymy test: in the present case it is due to the fact that the adjectives are gradable ones that can apply either to the scale generally *(How deep is the water?)* or to an area of the scale greater than some relevant norm *(The water is deep).* The compound involves the first use, whereas the adjectives are generally interpreted in the second way when standing alone.
>
> ### Incorporated complement/modifier
>
> [28]  *accident-prone    burglar-proof    camera-shy      carsick              cholesterol-free*
>  
>             *class-conscious    girl-crazy           oil-rich               power-mad      praiseworthy*
>             *snow-blind           tax-free               travel-weary    user-friendly    watertight*
>
> These are comparable to syntactic constructions where the adjective has a  following PP as dependent, complement, or modifier - compare *prone to accidents, proof against burglars, crazy about girls, rich in oil,* etc. *Free* (both in the sense "not having to pay", as in *tax-free,* and in the sense "not containing", as in *cholesterol-free*) is particularly productive. Some adjectives, such as *crazy, free, mad, rich, weary, worthy,* occur readily both in compounds and in syntactic constructions, while others, such as *proof* and *tight,* prefer or require the compound form.<sup>26</sup> Others again take syntactic complements but hardly form compounds: *fond of animals, keen on sport, eager for revenge* (compare **animal-fond, *sport-keen/*sports-keen, *revenge-eager*). Where the noun corresponds to a syntactic complement, the compounds are generally not hyponymic: *tax-free goods* aren't (necessarily) free, nor is a *user-friendly computer manual* a friendly one. With *prone* and *proof* the issue does not in fact arise since they cannot stand alone without complements - and indeed the same applies to *free* and *conscious* in the senses they have in *cholesterol-free* and *class-conscious.*
>
> <sup><sup>26</sup>*Fail-safe* and *tamper-proof* are exceptional in that the first base is a verb rather than noun.</sup>

There is another type that involves compounds with *self* (*self-confident, self-conscious, self-evident, self-important, self-righteous*), but that's clearly not relevant.

We've said that *cop-flat* is an adjective-centred compound adjective; now the question becomes, of what type? It is not comparative/intensifying: the noun *cop* does indicates a standard of comparison—the author is not trying to say that her eyes were **as** flat as that of a cop, but rather that they had the quality of flatness that is characteristic of cops. *Cop-flat* is also not  a measure term, for the same reason. Moreover, measure terms are not supposed to be [hyponymic](https://books.google.com/books?id=jQA6wVLCINUC&lpg=PA292&dq=hyponymy&pg=PA292#v=onepage&q=hyponymy&f=false), but *cop-flat* is: her eyes being cop-flat does imply they were flat. The final category, that of incorporated complement/modifier, seems to fit the best. First of all, some examples of it are hyponymic: being travel-weary does imply that one is weary, for example. Also, *cop-flat* is indeed comparable to a syntactic construction where the adjective has a following PP as dependent, complement, or modifier: to say that Eve's eyes were cop-flat is to say that Eve's eyes were flat *in the manner of a cop's eyes.*

Comment: Jill Elizabeth must have pinched it from him. He seems to have used it first.

Comment: @Lambie Quite possible… (BTW, it's a *she*; J. D. Robb is a pseudonym of Nora Roberts.)

Comment: Oh boy, one lady copping a term from another. Ha ha.

Comment: This is an admirably detailed explanation of what this phrase means within the work of **one particular author** who coined it, and one other author who appears to have borrowed it from her. However, insofar as the question seems to ask what this phrase means in general, a complete answer to it should acknowledge that that the phrase has **no** definite meaning that would be readily recognized by a person who hasn't read the work of these particular authors.

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure, but I think that *cop flat* means 'police eyed', meaning 'searching the mystery'.

Comment: Hi sunita, welcome to ELU StackExchange! Thank you for answering the question. However, your contribution will be best received if you follow the following guidelines, among others: 1. Please proofread your answer for mistakes in word usage, grammar, and punctuation. 2. Please support your claims with argument and references from reputable sources. Mere opinion is usually not enough. 3. Please pay attention to any answers already given and any debate in the comments.

Comment: For example, in my answer to this question, you may see other instances of uses of *cop flat* by the same author that seem more consistent with a different interpretation than the one you've given. Moreover, none of the dictionary meanings of the word *flat* would seem to be consistent with your interpretation. (By the way, it was not me who downvoted.)